# DNS and Http HOST header issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, http, sharepoint-2007

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. And I am using publishing portal template. I have a physical server with a single IP address, and I have set in DNS to map two domain names (server1.mycorp.com and server2.mycorp.com) to the same server/IP address.

My question is how to setup two SharePoint web sites on the same server with a single IP address to serve two domain names individually (with the same port number 80)? My current idea is to create two SharePoint web applications for the two web sites, with the same port number 80, but with different host header (setup Http host header to server1.mycorp.com and server2.mycorp.com individually for the two SharePoint web applications). Not sure whether my idea is feasible?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1):

> My current idea is to create two SharePoint web applications for the two web sites, with the same port number 80, but with different host header (setup Http host header to server1.mycorp.com and server2.mycorp.com individually for the two SharePoint web applications). Not sure whether my idea is feasible?

Yes, that is exactly how this is done - both for SharePoint and for any other type of web-site.